# Next.js page's first paint is missing all styles

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using scss to style my next.js app however I noticed that all styles are missing when I preview the first paint via the network tab in google chrome.

[image: missing styles]

As you can see the page is fairly simple and does not fetch any initial props. I'm suspecting that the server is for some reason not building the whole page (including styles) on the backend.

My next.config.js setup is:
const withStyles = require("@webdeb/next-styles");

```
  module.exports = withStyles({
  sass: true, // use .scss files
  modules: true, // style.(m|module).css & style.(m|module).scss for module files
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

With newer nextjs versions, I don't think you need to use `withStyles` and similar plugins anymore.

#### global styles only

You can just:

- install [sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass)
- install whatever css framework you're using and follow their instructions for how to include their css / scss files in your project
- potentially get rid of your `next.config.js` file entirely if it's a simple project and all you had in the config file was css configuration stuff.
- import your scss files directly into your js files (eg `import '../styles/app.scss'`)

#### scoped scss styles

- seems you can keep the `next.config.js` file, based on this workaround I found [here](https://dev.to/vladymyrpylypchatin/comment/m7fg) through a google search:

```js
const withStyles = require('@webdeb/next-styles')

module.exports = withStyles({
  sass: true, // use .scss files
  modules: true, // style.(m|module).css & style.(m|module).scss for module files
})
```

Comment: Hi yen, so I did as you said and deleted the `next.config.js` file. However after doing so I kept getting this error `Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Please move all global CSS imports to src/pages/_app.js. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).` I then imported all the component specifc scss files of the home page into _app.js however the issue still persists

Comment: @insivika I expanded my answer based on searching for the errors you describe. Some docs [here too](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css)

Comment: I'm not sure how this fixes my issue. That the setup i had when I orginally posted the problem

Comment: Hey there @insivika, Were you able to find a solution for this?